# Connect to ipage database with java

Tags: java, mysql

I am trying to connect to mysql database hosted on iPage, this is my code

```
public void addUser(){
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        Connection conn = null;
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://tt.ipagemysql.com","my_user", "password");
        conn.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But I get an exception

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
```